# create graphviz graph using md arrays from php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, image-graphviz

Hy, I'm looking for a way to create a GraphViz graph from php arrays. I have an associative multidimensional array from which I need to extract the keys and their corresponding values, and use them to create a graph. Example by 1D array:

```
$arr = ("dogs" => "4", "cats" => "3");
```

I need to extract the key "dogs" and use it as the label of a nod, and extract the corresponding value "4" and somehow use that to define the size of that nod.
I need to do the same thing with multidimensional arrays. Just a silly example:

```
$md_arr = ("dogs" => array("rot" => "7", "blood_hound" => "4"), 
           "cats" => array("long_hair" => "12", "some_other_kind" => "1")
          );
```

I need the output to be defined something like this:

name/label of the first node: first key from the first array => "dogs"
name/label of the second node: first key from the second array => "rot" , size of that node is a value of the corresponding key - in this case "7".

I also need to know how to pass the variable from my array_script.php (script that creates my MD array) to a new script that will create the graph. I tried putting the example code for creating graph into my php script, and the output was a warning message stating:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\hare.php:1) in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Image\GraphViz.php on line 174
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I figured it out on my own :)
[link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php)
the trick is to use `addNode` function. In my case, I needed to create dynamic graph using data from dynamicaly populated MD array. So you just need to name the node with a variable containing data you need. I needed the label to be set by the value from a variable as well, so here's the code:
`$graph->addNode($var1, array('label' => $var1));
$graph->addNode($var2, array('label' => $var2));
$graph->addEdge(array($var1 => $var2))`
works if var names are same, but values are differnet

Comment: Can you please put this in as an answer to your own question. You can select your own answer as answering the question. This adds value to StackOverflow and helps everyone else - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on my own :) link the trick is to use addNode function. In my case, I needed to create dynamic graph using data from dynamicaly populated MD array. So you just need to name the node with a variable containing data you need. I needed the label to be set by the value from a variable as well, so here's the code: $graph->addNode($var1, array('label' => $var1)); $graph->addNode($var2, array('label' => $var2)); $graph->addEdge(array($var1 => $var2)) works if var names are same, but values are differnet

6 years late to the party, but hey!
I do apologize to the community. I have no idea what was happening 6 years ago.